# Sum up column values in datagrid based on the value of another column in c# windows

Tags: c#, windows, datagrid

I have a datagrid with many columns. 
Below are two of those columns. 
I  need to add up the count values for P and F values of P/F column seperately and compare them.for P the sum is 3 and for F it is 7. I need to display the sum with greater value. Is there any way i can achieve dis.

```
P/F | Count
------------------------
P   | 2
P   | 1
F   | 5
F   | 2
```

Using Linq

```
 var p_sum = from p_col in dataGridView1  //-->  am getting error here(group by not found)
  group p_col  by p_col.Status into g 
  select g.Sum(p => p.weightagepercent) ;
```

Comment: What are you using: Winforms? WPF ? what .Net version? did you include the `using` for the linq?

Comment: using winforms. yes have included using

Comment: Which .Net version? and can you try something simple like `var v = from p_col in dataGridView1 where p_col.your_count_var_name_here select p_col.your_count_var_name_here ;` just to see if linq works

Comment: Am getting error in datagridview1. red line below it...
using framework 4, vs2010

Comment: That's great. Now, the last thing you'll need to do is update your question with how you built your datagrid, and what are the columns (you could have some input example as well), and you should be able to get a decent answer that will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Linq.
Below is a simple working code

```
double sumP = 0;
double sumF = 0;

for (int i = 6; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; ++i)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.Equals("P"))
    {
        sumP += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value);
    }
    else if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.Equals("F"))
    {
        sumF += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value);
    }
}

If(sumF>sumP)
{
    Label2.text="Fail";
}
else
{
    label2.text="Pass";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use linq to do something like:

```
var p_sum = 
    from p_col in datagrid
    group p_col  by p_col.datagrid_p_f_column into g 
    select g.Sum(p => p.datagrid_value_column) };
```

Do the same for F, and then just show the bigger with a simple smaller, bigger, or max on both variables

---

Firs't learn linq. It'll make your life easier :) Here's the official [101 linq samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).

Let's assume I have an class called `ExtraStringDataPoint`, defined like this:

```
public class ExtraStringDataPoint : IDataPoint
{
    public ExtraStringDataPoint(double x, double y , string s)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Extra = s;
    }
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public string  Extra { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a collection of those points:

```
List<ExtraStringDataPoint> MyList = new List<ExtraStringDataPoint>()
{
    new ExtraStringDataPoint(10,10,"ten"),
    new ExtraStringDataPoint(20, 20, "twenty"),
    new ExtraStringDataPoint(30,30, "thirty")
};
```

You could use linq to sum all the point's value of Y, where the X value is bigger than 15 like this for example:

```
var bigger_than_15 = from point in MyList
                      where point.X > 15
                      select point;

var total_y = bigger_than_15.Sum(point => point.Y);
```

So, back to your case. Linq will group the item's according to your datagrid by the column that hold's the name (P or F) into a group. `p_col` is a temp variable, `datagrid_p_f_column` should be the column name (or property in an object, it's the same). Once the grouping is done, it will sum all the values. In your case for each `p`, it will sum `p.datagrid_value_column` which should be the name of the column holding your numeric value. In the end, `p_sum` will have the sum of the values of the row's where the name has `p`. Rinse and repeat for `f`. compare, and that's it.

Comment: can i include linq in my c# project. Am getting error with the above code

Comment: yes, you should include link, since this is what this is :) `using System.Linq;` should set you up. you might need to tweak the names a bit, but without your code and names, that's the git of it ...

Comment: ok..can i know the namings u hv used. What is gridview,p_col,p_f_ column? as i hvnt worked on linq

Comment: it sounds like you know what you want, so what's your question? write a loop, check the value, and store it (even though it's the harder longer way of doing it ...)

Comment: Am trying to use Linq..Am getting error as groupby not found.Please find my edited question where ststus and weightagepercen are two columns

Comment: The actual error is :Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'.  'GroupBy' not found.

Comment: where in my answer do you see GroupBy? :)

Comment: no where..But why am i getting that error. Is it the right way am using? Did u see my edited question

Answer (score 0):

```
int countF=0;
int countP=0;

foreach(DataRow row in DataTable.rows)
{
    if(row.itemArray[0].tostring().equals("F")
            {
                countf++;
            }
            `if(row.itemArray[0].tostring().equals("P")`
            {
                countP++;
            }
        }
        if(countF>countP)
{
    Display
}
else

Display
```

//for dataGrid View

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("P","1");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("F","2");
        int countF = 0;
        int countP = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
        {
           string a= dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString();
           string b = dataGridView1[1, i].Value.ToString();
           if (a == "F")
           {
               countF= Convert.ToInt32(b);
               countF++;
           }
           if (a == "P")
           {
               countF = Convert.ToInt32(b);
               countP++;
           }
            }
        if (countF > countP)
        {
            //display
        }
        else
        {
            //display
        }
```

Comment: Am using a datagridview